# iCal URL Scheme OS X

Tags: html, macos, calendar, icalendar, url-scheme

I'm trying to create a link to create an iCal event, preferably without a file.

Is there any way to create an event using URL parameters only on OS X? I noticed that links with iCal:// as their protocol load up Calendar, but I can't see a URL Scheme definition anywhere.

Is there any other way to achieve this? Again, preferably just by using parameters rather than triggering an ICS file download.

I've searched SO but most of the questions relate specifically to iOS which I know is a whole different ball game.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically you should be able to do this with a data:// url. With the right content-type it *might* work. This would be the *standard way*, but if it's properly supported might depend on your browser.

Comment: Is there any way of specify an extension type when calling data://?

Comment: What's an extension type?